# Three.js Fog , max opacity

Tags: javascript, three.js

***What I am attempting:***

I am building a lightweight GIS application that includes topography. One thing I would like to add is atmosphere haze.

***My current code:***

(Please excuse my code, I have multiple scenes)

```
  fogColor = new THREE.Color(0x7EC0EE);
  this.scenes[name].background = fogColor;
  this.scenes[name].fog = new THREE.Fog(fogColor, 250, 2000);
  //alternatively:
  this.scenes[name].fog = new THREE.FogExp2( fogColor, .001 )
```

***Problem encountered:***

Both Fog and FogExp2 work well for the units of scale in my app when I am close to the ground. However when moving the camera farther above the ground, and looking down, eventually the earth turns 100% blue, as its obscured by the fog setting.

***My Question:***

*Is there a way to apply a max opacity to the fog?*

I would like the topography to stay hazy at a distance but not completely obscured by fog as a solid color. I was thinking I could calculate the furthest object in view, and adjust the fog setting on every camera change, but I am not sure how or if I am overthinking this. I'd like to calculate fog based on the amount of "air" between the camera and the object and never go over a certain opacity of fog. Is this done better in a shader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to apply max opacity to fog, but you could change the fog's [`near` and `far` parameters](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/scenes/Fog) on the fly. For example:

```
var origin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

update() {
    var dist = camera.position.distanceTo(origin);
    fog.far = 2000 + dist;
}
```

I'm not sure what kind of units you're dealing with, so you might need to play with the way you calculate `dist`. With this approach, the further you are from `0, 0, 0`, the further away the fog will reach.

With FogExp2, you could try modifying the [.density property](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/scenes/FogExp2.density).

Comment: This worked. Instead of 2000+dist, I doubled my dist and used my near:  fog.far = (dist*2) + fog.near; This has a perfect effect. Thank you!